# Div's width adjusting if another div is hidden or not?

Tags: html

In my body i want two divs with content side by side that each has a width of 50% of the screen. But i want to be able to hide/show the first div and then the second divs width responds to this changing it's width to 100% or 50%. Filling the body or the rest of the body depending on if the first div is hidden.

Any ideas how to do this? (I know how to show/hide with jquery, im thinking of the HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use floating only to the first element, and let the second one fit the remaining space.

Then, if the element is visible with `width:50%`, the second one will fill the other half. But if the first one is hidden, the second one will fill whole screen.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4C5E/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" />
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Foo</div>
    <div id="right">Bar</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper, #right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ffa;
}
#right {
    background-color: #faf;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var left = document.getElementById('left');
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    left.className = left.className ? '' : 'hide';
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost working. I think something is wrong with the second div though. I have a map in the second div and if i start with it filling the whole area and then show the first div (with 50% width) the second div adjust and changes it's width but it seems to just push the map-center out to the right not actually changing size.. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3199840 Not sure what you mean. If the right one has 100% width and becomes 50%, its left side will be pushed to the right. If it didn't move, it would mean that the size didn't have changed, wouldn't it?

Comment: I've edited my first post. Maybe it has to do with the map settings. But when the map-div changes to 50% the center of the map is not adjusting to the new div width but get pushed outside of the visible div. Hard to explain.

Comment: I think the problem is with the map. I'll start a separate post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3199840 Not at all :) The problem is because of `width: 100%; position: fixed; display:inline-block`. You must remove them in order to make it work.

Comment: Yeah thats was my first idea also. But it seems i have to have these setting to make it fill the div.  When i remove them the map changes it's height (no idea why? really strange behaviour) Maybe i can wrap it in another div or something? But yes there is no centering problem with this solution! :)

Comment: @user3199840 The problem is that `height:100%` only works with elements out of the normal flow of the document (e.g. fixed or absolute), or with elements whose parent has a height different than `auto`.

Comment: Ok. Hm. I really don't want to set the height in px. Is there a way to make it just fill the height the same way we did with the width? Because the problem is the same when i simply remove height.. Or should i switch to the table-approach?

Comment: @user3199840 See http://jsfiddle.net/C4C5E/3/. You can put the wrapper out of the flow of the document in order to make `height:100%` work (or equivalently `top:0;bottom:0`). And then, since its height is not `auto`, `height:100%` will work for the columns.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate your help! It looks OK now! But i think there is still some problems with the map-div and it's javascript library (leaflet) because it seems like it broke it's ability to determine what is the new "center" when the width changes. It probably doesnt allow for changing size so i may have to rethink this..

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: use `display: table-cell`. This has the advantage over floats that both columns will have same height, and setting wrapper's height will also set it for both columns.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4C5E/2/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" />
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Foo</div>
    <div id="right">Bar</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #right {
    display: table-cell;
}
#left {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
#right {
    background-color: #faf;
}
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
var left = document.getElementById('left');
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    left.className = left.className ? '' : 'hide';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox and JQuery to do this with as many divs as you'd like.

https://jsfiddle.net/L8kfty5n/5/

```js
function hideandshow() {
  if ($('.hide').is(":checked"))
    $("#div1").show();
  else
    $("#div1").hide();
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">This disappears</div>
  <div id="div2">This grows</div>
  <div id="div3">This grows too</div>
</div>
<input class="hide" type="checkbox" name="hide" value="1" onchange="hideandshow()" checked/>
```